# vim search for arbitrary combination of spaces and tabs

Tags: regular-expression, replace, whitespace

I'd like to construct a mapping that would replace `a   b` with `c` where the gap between a and b could be zero or more spaces or zero or more tabs, but not zero of both.    There have been several related postings: [This is the most promising of several postings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972089/how-to-create-a-regex-that-will-match-an-arbitrary-sequence-of-spaces-and-tabs), which addresses the problem in terms of regexp, but I can't get their syntax to work in vim.   Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're looking for a `substitute` command:

```
:s/a[ \t]\+b/c/
```

The default regex mode doesn't see `+` as an operator. You have to escape it to make it special.

You can also use:

```
:s/a\s\+b/c/
```

[`\s`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cs) is Vim's shortcut for space and tabs in regex.